# Two expressions of kinetic energy of rotation

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, linear-algebra, moment-of-inertia

The moment of inertia matrix for rigid body in general case is
$I=
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy} & I_{yz}\\
I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}
$
The angular momentum is $M=I\Omega \equiv M_j=\sum_{i=1}^3I_{ji}\Omega_i$.
I need to prove the following expression:
$\sum_{i,j=1}^3\Omega_iI_{ji}\Omega_j=\sum_{i,j=1}^3M_i[I^{-1}]_{ji}M_j$
I am struggling to prove this in case when **I** isn't a diagonal matrix, any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I will use Einsteins-summation convention to make it more readable, this means I will sum over indices that occur twice within a product, i.e. e.g. $I_{ij} \Omega_j \equiv \sum_{j=1}^3 I_{ij} \Omega_j$.

So, the way to get your equation is as follows:

$\Omega_i \; I_{ji} \; \Omega_j \enspace = \enspace M_j \; \Omega_j \qquad \text{(1)}$

Now use:

$\Omega \enspace = \enspace I^{-1} \; M \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad \Omega_j \enspace = \enspace I^{-1}_{jk} \; M_{k}$

Substitute $\Omega_j$ on the right-hand-side of equation (1). This yields:

$\Omega_i \; I_{ji} \; \Omega_j \enspace = \enspace M_j \; I^{-1}_{jk} \; M_{k}$

Since these are all just components, you are allowed to commute within the last product. So you have

$\Omega_i \; I_{ji} \; \Omega_j \enspace = \enspace M_k \; I^{-1}_{jk} \; M_j$

The summation index $k$ can be renamed whatever you want it be named, especially you can name it $i$, which will lead to your equation.